# Draggable element gets stuck near edges

Tags: javascript

Dragging the element seems to make it get stuck randomly before touching the edges of its parent container. Would someone be able to spot why this is going on?

On a side note, I could not get the remembered position transferred to "updateDrag" correctly.

And no, I don't want any jQuery solution, like one created with jQuery UI.

```js
let $container = document.getElementById('container');
let $element = document.getElementById('element');
let mousePosition;
let offset = [0, 0];
let isDown = false;

function initDrag(event) {
  isDown = true;
  // Element also remembers previous position wrong
  // offset = [
  //     $element.offsetLeft - event.clientX,
  //     $element.offsetTop - event.clientY
  // ];
  offset = [
    0,
    0
  ];
}

function updateDrag(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (isDown) {
    mousePosition = {
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    };
    let diffY = mousePosition.y - offset[1];
    let diffX = mousePosition.x - offset[0];

    if (diffY >= 0 && diffY + $element.offsetHeight <= $container.offsetHeight) {
      $element.style.top = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
    if (diffX >= 0 && diffX + $element.offsetWidth <= $container.offsetWidth) {
      $element.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function haltDrag() {
  isDown = false;
}

$element.addEventListener('mousedown', initDrag, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', haltDrag, false);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', updateDrag, false);
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

#element {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this doesn’t happen because the mouse pointer is no longer on the element?

Comment: You mean the effect that the red square keeps a small distance away from the side, even though the mouse cursor has already crossed the boundary? That's because you ignore mouse events outside the green area. Mousemove event rate is limited; the faster you move, the bigger the distance between the locations where the event fires.

Comment: Aha, is contact lost between "initDrag" to "updateDrag" since the "mousedown" listener only listens on element "$element"? If you can correct this into an answer, then it would be much appreciated for an upvote! Thanks

Comment: You misunderstood; `updateDrag` listens across the entire document. The problem is in your own `if` statements; get rid of them. Instead, use `Math.min` and `Math.max` to bound the red box's freedom of movement.